# Data mules in ns2

Tags: ns2

I want to create a 2x4 grid in ns2 in which sensor nodes are deployed uniformly in each grid. Now the only function of sensor nodes sense data and communicate it to data mules(mobile nodes) To ensure equal node on every mobile node, the sensor nodes are uniformly placed. I am using 8 mobile nodes(one node in each grid) and 100 sensing nodes.
So far I have completed my grid and introduce mobile nodes in it as well. Now what i need to do is to attach the mobile nodes with sensor nodes so that when a sensor nodes comes in radius of mobile node, it sends data to it. Just tell me how can i attach mobile agent(data mules) with sensor node. I am not asking for any code, just tell me any document which can help me in this matter.
Thanks!

Comment: From the rules: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Answer (score 0):

For doing this, you can write a "hello Like" protocol or a beacon protocol.

If a mobile agent(data mules) starts to move, it should send a "hello" or "beacon" message. A sensor node which hears that "hello" or "beacon" message will start to send data to that mobile agent.

You can see a similar project in the following link :
http://www.projectguideline.com/a-simple-vanet-protocol-simulation-using-tcl-level-functions-of-ns-2/
In that VANET project, the stationary nodes will do something while receiving the beacon of the moving node(vehicle).
You may design your protocol based on this model.